# Comparing n strings in java

Tags: java, string, string-matching

Does anyone know the fastest way of comparing a single string to `n` number of strings for a match?

For eg: The word "example" needs to be compared with a list, containing `n` number of words, for a match. The list may contain any number of words, of any length.

Is there a specific algorithm I can use to do this? I know of string matching algorithms which find a substring within a string, such as the Boyer-Moore Algorithm. But not for this one. Please help me out here. Note that I will be implementing this in Java.

Comment: Is the word list sorted or indexed in any way? Otherwise you just have to do you Boyer-Moore for each one of them in a loop.

Comment: What kind of match? The answers assume that by "match" you mean "find exactly the same string", not a substring, for example.

Comment: the strings are not sorted in anyway, and yes i am trying to get an exact match(case insensitive)

Comment: "case insensitive" changes this quite a bit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prepare a `Map<Int,List<String>>` for your list where the key is the `.hashcode()` for the string and the List contains all strings with the same hashcode.

Then you just look up the hashcode for your new string,and run equals() on each string in the returned list.

Should be much faster as there are much fewer entries to compare.  Note that the preparation needs some time, so only do this if you need to do it more than once.

Comment: please explain how to make this work for case insensitive match (see the comments on the question).

Comment: If the strings can be lowercased and still make sense, then lowercase them before processing.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

```
List<String> lstr = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"});
Collections.sort(lstr); 

lstr.contains("c"); // true
lstr.contains("f"); // false
```

Comment: Does not work with a case insensitive match (see the comments on the question).

Answer (score 2):

Run a loop till end of the list and compare each element using **equals()** method

Comment: +1 Or equalsIgnoreCase in this case. Also, possibly break out on the first match.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to check for an exact match, then you can either maintain a hash map of your dictionary and look up the hash of the word, or use a tree like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie where each node is a letter.

Both would be nearly constant time complexity compared to the number of words, and instead depend on the length of the word you are looking up (insignificant).

Comment: Assumes that you need to do this more than once for the same list.